# Biblatex - show first author, second author, ..., last author

Tags: biblatex, author

I have a style in my bibliography that I need to follow. The style is "ieee" but with a custom format of the authors.

Normal ieee:
A. Uthor, W. Riter, R. Esearcher, S. C. Ientist, S. T. Udent, P. R. Ofessor, and L. E. C. Turer, “A very interesting article with a lot of authors,” Journal of Articles, vol. 5, no. 8, pp. 8–12, 2012. doi: 12345/6789.10.

What I want:
A. Uthor, W. Riter, ..., and L. E. C. Turer, “A very interesting article with a lot of authors,” Journal of Articles, vol. 5, no. 8, pp. 8–12, 2012. doi: 12345/6789.10.

I.e., I want authors number 3 through (n-1) to **not be shown** but \ldots instead.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Minimal not working example (Ref 1 should be abbreviated and Ref 2 should stay the same):

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber,maxnames=999]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testartlong,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter and Rita Esearcher and Steven C. Ientist and Stuart T. Udent and Peter R. Ofessor and Lewis E. C. Turer},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article With a Lot of Authors},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {5},
  number        = {8},
  pages         = {8-12},
  date          = {2012},
  doi           = {12345/6789.10},
}
@article{testart,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  number        = {3},
  pages         = {1-5},
  date          = {2010},
  issn          = {1234-5678},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  Test
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
  \end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related [Using the “et Int” citation system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/377543/35864)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber,maxnames=999]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testartlong,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter and Rita Esearcher and Steven C. Ientist and Stuart T. Udent and Peter R. Ofessor and Lewis E. C. Turer},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article With a Lot of Authors},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {5},
  number        = {8},
  pages         = {8-12},
  date          = {2012},
  doi           = {12345/6789.10},
}
@article{testart,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  number        = {3},
  pages         = {1-5},
  date          = {2010},
  issn          = {1234-5678},
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareNameFormat{FirstLast}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listtotal}=1}
    {\namepartgiveni\adddot\addspace\ifblank{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addnbspace}\namepartfamily}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{listtotal}=2}
      {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{listtotal}}
        {\namepartgiveni\adddot\addspace\ifblank{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addnbspace}\namepartfamily\addspace}
        {\bibstring{and}\addspace\namepartgiveni\adddot\addspace\ifblank{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addnbspace}\namepartfamily}}
      {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
        {\namepartgiveni\adddot\addspace\ifblank{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addnbspace}\namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace\dots\isdot\addcomma \addspace and}
        {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{listtotal}}
          {}
          {\addspace\namepartgiveni\adddot\addspace\ifblank{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addnbspace}\namepartfamily}}%
      }%
    }%
}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{FirstLast}

\begin{document}
  Test
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
  \end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More or less adapted from this [Biblatex citations first and last author only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139329/biblatex-citations-first-and-last-author-only/139389#139389)

### Edit

The following seems to work too:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{FirstLast}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listtotal} < 3}
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {{\renewcommand\finalnamedelim{\addcomma\addspace\dots\isdot\addcomma \addspace\bibstring{and}\addspace}%
        \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1 \OR \value{listcount}=\value{listtotal}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
        {}}%     
    }%
  }%
```

Comment: I'd have preferred if this solution called `\usebibmacro{name:given-family}` or `\usebibmacro{name:family-given}` instead of trying to format the names directly. That way the names obey `\ifuseprefix`, `\ifprefchar`, `\mkbibname...` etc.

Comment: @moewe I was to lazy ;-). Perhaps I will edit later. Are you already a TUG member? If not consider to add your name here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7543/tug-representatives-for-2018

Comment: I see. Maybe I should complain to Guido as well. In fact I became a Dante+TUG member this January.

Comment: @moewe I can't use `\usebibmacro{name:given-family}`. I get errors like `! You can't use `\begingroup' after \advance.
\ifprefchar ->\ifhmode \begingroup ` .

Comment: I'll have a look later. It should work I'd have thought.

Comment: @moewe: I'm dump, forgot the arguments ...